# How to remove duplicates and matching original elements from list using java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, collections

I have already tried using a Set Collection to remove duplicates but this does not solve what i am asking here.

I am trying to accomplish the following task: I have a list
`Integer [] list1 = {1,2,3,3};`
i want to remove the duplicates but also I want to remove the matching pair, so the result i want is
`{1,2}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a frequency map to filter the elements having a frequency greater than 2.

- The frequency map `freqMap` has the entries: `{1=1, 2=1, 3=2}`, we just need to filter the entries having a value greater than 2 `.filter(e -> e.getValue()<2)` which is `{3=2}` here.
- Now we have the entries:  `{1=1, 2=1}` But we want only the keys `{1, 2}` so we use `map()` function to get the keys: `.map(e -> e.getKey())`

Try this:

```
Map<Integer, Long> freqMap = Arrays.stream(list1)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

int[] result = freqMap.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue() < 2).map(e -> e.getKey()).mapToInt(m -> m).toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

Output:

```
[1, 2]
```

Comment: this is some advanced sh* for me, but it worked like a charm, thanks

Comment: You can ask for details that you don't understand. I'm adding some explanation...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Map. Count the number of times the elements appear in a <int, int> map and get only those keys that have a count of 1.

so then this is what you have for your example,

```
{

  1: 1,
  2: 1,
  3: 2,

}
```

Then just extract keys 1 and 2 since they have a count of 1. O(n) time and space.

Comment: welcome. i dont think this can be done in better time but lets see if someone gives an O(1) space solution

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was to get a set from the list, then remove all elements in the list that are in the set, and remove all elements in the set that are in the remaining list.

```
    Integer[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 3 };
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arr));
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(list);
    for (Iterator<Integer> iterator = set.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        list.remove(iterator.next());
    }
    set.removeAll(list);
    System.out.println(list);
    System.out.println(set);
```

Output:

```
[3]
[1, 2]
```

This will work with versions of Java less than Java 8. Otherwise just use freqMap() as answered by Hülya.